# How to get selected values in SumoSelect dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sumoselect.js

I am using the [SumoSelect](https://hemantnegi.github.io/jquery.sumoselect/) dropdown for multiselect options. But i cannot get the selected values array.
Below the sample code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {         
    window.testSelAll = $('.testSelAll').SumoSelect({okCancelInMulti:true, selectAll:true });           

        $('.btnOk').on('click', function(){
            var obj = [];
            $('option:selected').each(function () {
                obj.push($(this).index());  
                alert("Selected Values=="+$(this).val());   
            });

            for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {                      
                $('.testSelAll')[0].sumo.unSelectItem(obj[i]);
            }
        });                 
    });

</script>

<select multiple="multiple" placeholder="Share Your Friends" onchange="console.log($(this).children(':selected').length)" class="testSelAll">
                <option value="1">Volvo</option>
               <option value="2">Saab</option>
               <option  value="3">Mercedes</option>
               <option value="audi">Audi</option>
               <option value="bmw">BMW</option>
               <option value="porsche">Porche</option>
               <option value="ferrari">Ferrari</option>
               <option value="mitsubishi">Mitsubishi</option>
       </select>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want the selected **values** instead of the **text**, just change `.text()` to `.val()`.

If you want to get the array, see below with working example at the bottom.

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.testSelAll').SumoSelect({
    okCancelInMulti: true,
    selectAll: true
  });

  $('.btnOk').on('click', function() {
    var obj = [],
        items = '';
    $('.testSelAll option:selected').each(function(i) {
      obj.push($(this).val());
      $('.testSelAll')[0].sumo.unSelectItem(i);
    });
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
      items += ' ' + obj[i]
    };
    alert(items);
  });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<select multiple="multiple" class="testSelAll">
  <option value="car1">Volvo</option>
  <option value="car2">Saab</option>
  <option value="car3">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="car4">Audi</option>
</select>
```

**[Working JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/cco8bewm/1/)**

Comment: @RamaLingam You're welcome. Please mark as correct answer if it solved your problem. Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

You can get them from underlying hidden select element.
using jquery eg.

```
$('.select1 option:selected')
```

Comment: I want the selected array values.

Comment: can u provide a fiddle?

Answer (score 2):

I think the cleanest way to do this. Is to take advantage of html5 select element underlying SumoSelect.

**HTML**

```
<select multiple="multiple" class="testSelAll" id="multi-select">
  <option value="car1">Volvo</option>
  <option value="car2">Saab</option>
  <option value="car3">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="car4">Audi</option>
</select>
```

**Javascript**

```
var values = $('#multi-select').val();
```

This line will return a string list of the values selected.